# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ConsoleCancelEventHandler' from assembly 'System.Console

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm learning asp.net 5 by running the github examples, specifically aspnet-Home. Things are good, until I get this error when I run

dnx . web

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ConsoleCancelEventHandler' from assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main(String[] args)

It happened earlier and a reboot fixed it. Rebooting sucks. Nothing found in Google. Anyone recognize this, and can explain how to resolve?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to write/call `Main` method in the web application. Try to create **Console Application** in the Visual Studio, this kind of application should contain `Main` method and may to use `System.Console` class.

Answer (score 1):

I had dnvm used the wrong execution environment. That's something I'm still figuring out.